# RegExp : At least 10 characters, with 1 upper case letter, with one lower case letter and or 1 special character or number)

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to check the following:

- Has at least 10 characters
- Has at least 1 upper case letter
- Has at least 1 lower case letter
- Spaces are allowed

Then at least one of the following.  Meaning not both are required.

- Number
- Special character (Special character is not considered a space)

I have the following regular expression

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{10,}$
```

It works well but it currently requires both a number and a special character.

I need the following to be valid:

- JohnDoe1234567891011 (numbers only)
- Johndoe!!!!!!!!!!!!! (special characters only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just move your special characters into the same group of characters as the numbers, like below:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{10,}$
```